# How can I prove that $d_{2}(f,g)=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}((f-g)^{2}+(f'-g')^{2})}$ is a metric for $C^{1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, metric-spaces

I need to proof that $d_{2}(f,g)=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}((f-g)^{2}+(f'-g')^{2})}$ is a metric space for $C^{1}$.
But i'm stuck in how can I prove that $d_{2}(f,g)\leq d_{2}(f,h)+d_{2}(h,g)$ and i don´t know if i need to use some inequalities or Riemann integral properties. Please Help :(

Comment: Do you mean $d_2(f,g)\color{red}{\le}d_2(f,h)+d_2(h,g)$?

Comment: What are $f'$ and $g'$? Derivatives?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I wrote the wrong problem.

Comment: Yes, f' and g' are the derivatives

Comment: Try to prove it for the metric without $f', g'$ first. Or maybe you can look it up somewhere.